# How can I see execution time of an ALTER TABLE statement?

Tags: postgresql, explain

Is it possible to see the execution time of an `alter table` command?

I think with `\timing` on in psql, it shows more than the execution time, but also the client round trip, and maybe other things as well. What I want is the "execution time" shown by `explain analyze`. But I can't run `alter table` through `explain analyze` (right?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run alter table commands through EXPLAIN ANALYZE.

You could use `\timing` and compare that with other queries and do some math to see the overhead, but I think I'd probably recommend wrapping the DDL statement between 2 `select now();` commands (all in the same line, to eliminate round trips). Technically this will also have some additional overhead, but probably less than `\timing`.

You might also just try turning on log_statement and log_duration in the conf, and capturing the timing of the command there. Anything more specific though and you'd probably need something overly low level like strace or gdb.

Comment: `log_duration` seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turn on `\timing`, run your `ALTER TABLE` and `SELECT 1`.

Subtract the values for a good estimate.

Comment: Thanks! datapoint: with log_duration on, psql timing for `select 1` is 0.368 ms, time in log is 0.157 ms

Comment: So my method would be off by 0.157 ms. But admittedly the other answer is better.

Comment: But your method is handy in environments where config can't be modified or log can't be accessed. I just realized—and I'd almost guess that this is what you had in mind—we can compare timing's value with `explain analyze select 1`. timing - execution time - planning time = client overhead.